# What is the name of the concept which distinguishes static and instance attributes

Tags: oop, naming

The concept of *public* and *private* variables is called *visibility*.

I'm looking for a concise word that describes the difference between *static attributes* and *instance attributes*. Is *scope* fitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "*ownership*" or "*relationship*" fits better, also the meaning can be somewhat different in different languages.

For example, in Python there are three types of such ownership:

- Instance attribute / method - *belongs* to the instance (or the instance *owns* it)
- Class method - *belongs* to the class (the class *owns* the attribute or method, here we can treat the class itself as an instance of higher-level class)
- Static attribute / method - logically *related* to the class, here the class name is used as a *namespace*

In C++ instance attributes / methods are *owned* by the instance and static attributes are logically *related* to the class. We just use the class name as an additional namespace to refer to the static attributes or methods.

In php static attributes are similar to C++, but there is also is also [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) which affects how static methods work with inheritance.
So it depends on the usage - static methods are either just "*related*" to the class or "*owned*" by the class (when the late static binding is used).

Regarding the "*scope*" term - I think it doesn't fit because it is used to describe how the compiler / interpreter finds the meaning of the specific name in the specific context.
For example, if you have global variable `x` and local with same name inside the function, the *scope* defines which of these two variables will be used.